# Symbols in query-string for Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, elasticsearch, tire

I have "documents" (activerecords) with an attribute called deviations. The attribute has values like "Bin X" "Bin $" "Bin q" "Bin %" etc.

I am trying to use tire/elasticsearch to search the attribute. I am using the whitespace analyzer to index the deviation attribute. Here is my code for creating the indexes:

```rb
settings :analysis => {
    :filter  => {
      :ngram_filter => {
        :type => "nGram",
        :min_gram => 2,
        :max_gram => 255
      },
      :deviation_filter => {
        :type => "word_delimiter",
        :type_table => ['$ => ALPHA']
      }
    },
    :analyzer => {
      :ngram_analyzer => {
        :type  => "custom",
        :tokenizer  => "standard",
        :filter  => ["lowercase", "ngram_filter"]
      },
      :deviation_analyzer => {
        :type => "custom",
        :tokenizer => "whitespace",
        :filter => ["lowercase"]
      }
    }
  } do
    mapping do
      indexes :id, :type => 'integer'
      [:equipment, :step, :recipe, :details, :description].each do |attribute|
        indexes attribute, :type => 'string', :analyzer => 'ngram_analyzer'
      end
      indexes :deviation, :analyzer => 'whitespace'
    end
  end
```

The search seems to work fine when the query string contains no special characters. For example `Bin X` will return only those records that have the words `Bin` AND `X` in them. However, searching for something like `Bin $` or `Bin %` shows all results that have the word `Bin` almost ignoring the symbol (results with the symbol do show up higher in the search that results without).

Here is the search method I have created

```rb
def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true) do
        query { string "#{params[:term].downcase}:#{params[:query]}", default_operator: "AND" }
        size 1000
    end
end
```

and here is how I am building the search form:

```html
<div>
    <%= form_tag issues_path, :class=> "formtastic issue", method: :get do %>
        <fieldset class="inputs">
        <ol>
            <li class="string input medium search query optional stringish inline">
                <% opts = ["Description", "Detail","Deviation","Equipment","Recipe", "Step"] %>
                <%= select_tag :term, options_for_select(opts, params[:term]) %>
                <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
                <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn" %>
            </li>
        </ol>
        </fieldset>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't just escape the characters have a meaning to Lucene with a backslash? Of course, in a Ruby string you'd need a double backslash \\ to escape the ruby character before it hits the Elastic Search api. I've not tried Tire, so I don't know if it works in your world. FYI, here is a quick reference to the characters affected: http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/lweug/Escaping+Special+Syntax+Characters

Comment: I don't think this is the issue because queries Bin $ or Bin % are affected, but they are not listed in the link above as a special character.

Comment: I know from my own experience of full text search in databases (Oracle I think it was, and MySQL for LIKE tests in varchar or text fields) that % is a 'match everything' character. Maybe that link above is incomplete, or maybe its not relevant to your issue. Have you tried escaping to see if that solves the problem?

Comment: Escaping the special characters with \ (for example Bin \%) or \\ (for example Bin \\%) has no effect on the behavior.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can sanitize your query string. Here is a sanitizer that works for everything that I've tried throwing at it:

```rb
def sanitize_string_for_elasticsearch_string_query(str)
  # Escape special characters
  # http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping Special Characters
  escaped_characters = Regexp.escape('\\/+-&|!(){}[]^~*?:')
  str = str.gsub(/([#{escaped_characters}])/, '\\\\\1')

  # AND, OR and NOT are used by lucene as logical operators. We need
  # to escape them
  ['AND', 'OR', 'NOT'].each do |word|
    escaped_word = word.split('').map {|char| "\\#{char}" }.join('')
    str = str.gsub(/\s*\b(#{word.upcase})\b\s*/, " #{escaped_word} ")
  end

  # Escape odd quotes
  quote_count = str.count '"'
  str = str.gsub(/(.*)"(.*)/, '\1\"\3') if quote_count % 2 == 1

  str
end

params[:query] = sanitize_string_for_elasticsearch_string_query(params[:query])
```

Comment: I needed to add forward slash also to the `escaped_characters` array. `escaped_characters = Regexp.escape('\\+-&|!(){}[]^~*?:\/')` as it was breaking for strings with forward slash.

Comment: That's strange since `/` is not a special character in Lucene: http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters

Comment: Hi, please see http://50.16.250.253:9200/locations/location/_search?q=123%2F345 ..I think this is giving an error, because `/` is inside the string...when I escape with a `\\`, the error is resolved, http://50.16.250.253:9200/locations/location/_search?q=123%5C%2F345

Comment: Hi, quote escape regexp should be `str = str.gsub(/(.*)"(.*)/, '\1\"\2') if quote_count % 2 == 1`, because there is just two groups

Comment: Just want to note:
forward slash is now a special character and should be escaped. http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Escaping_Special_Characters

Comment: I've translated this solution to Scala here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107601/is-there-an-implementation-of-a-search-term-sanitizer-for-elasticsearch-in-scala/32107602

Comment: I've translated the solution to Python here https://gist.github.com/eranhirs/5c9ef5de8b8731948e6ed14486058842