# Is there an implementation of a search term sanitizer for Elasticsearch in Scala?

Tags: scala, elasticsearch

I'm looking for a method that would sanitize search terms passed to elastic search, i.e. escape all the control characters. Something like what is described in Ruby in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16442439/900130). Is there such a thing for Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are provided libs for this that you're probably better off using

```
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParserBase
....    
val escapedQ = QueryParserBase.escape(rawQuery)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've translated the solution for ruby found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16442439/900130) to Scala:

```
package util

import java.util.regex.Pattern

trait ElasticSearchSanitizer {
  /** Sanitizes special characters and set operators in elastic search search-terms. */
  def sanitize(term: String): String = (
    escapeSpecialCharacters _ andThen
    escapeSetOperators andThen
    collapseWhiteSpaces andThen
    escapeOddQuote
  )(term)

  private def escapeSpecialCharacters(term: String): String = {
    val escapedCharacters = Pattern.quote("""\/+-&|!(){}[]^~*?:""")
    term.replaceAll(s"([$escapedCharacters])", "\\\\$1")
  }

  private def escapeSetOperators(term: String): String = {
    val operators = Set("AND", "OR", "NOT")
    operators.foldLeft(term) { case (accTerm, op) =>
      val escapedOp = escapeEachCharacter(op)
      accTerm.replaceAll(s"""\\b($op)\\b""", escapedOp)
    }
  }

  private def escapeEachCharacter(op: String): String =
    op.toCharArray.map(ch => s"""\\\\$ch""").mkString

  private def collapseWhiteSpaces(term: String): String = term.replaceAll("""\s+""", " ")

  private def escapeOddQuote(term: String): String = {
    if (term.count(_ == '"') % 2 == 1) term.replaceAll("""(.*)"(.*)""", """$1\\"$2""") else term
  }
}
```

And here are the tests:

```
package util

import org.specs2.matcher.Matchers
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

class ElasticSearchSanitizerSpec extends Specification with Matchers {
  "sanitize" should {
    object S extends ElasticSearchSanitizer

    "escape special characters" in {
      S.sanitize("""back\slash""") mustEqual """back\\slash"""
      S.sanitize("""sl/ash""") mustEqual """sl\/ash"""
      S.sanitize("""pl+us""") mustEqual """pl\+us"""
      S.sanitize("""mi-nus""") mustEqual """mi\-nus"""
      S.sanitize("""amper&sand""") mustEqual """amper\&sand"""
      S.sanitize("""pi|pe""") mustEqual """pi\|pe"""
      S.sanitize("""ba!ng""") mustEqual """ba\!ng"""
      S.sanitize("""open(parenthesis""") mustEqual """open\(parenthesis"""
      S.sanitize("""close)parenthesis""") mustEqual """close\)parenthesis"""
      S.sanitize("""open{curly""") mustEqual """open\{curly"""
      S.sanitize("""close}curly""") mustEqual """close\}curly"""
      S.sanitize("""open[bracket""") mustEqual """open\[bracket"""
      S.sanitize("""close[bracket""") mustEqual """close\[bracket"""
      S.sanitize("""circum^flex""") mustEqual """circum\^flex"""
      S.sanitize("""til~de""") mustEqual """til\~de"""
      S.sanitize("""aste*risk""") mustEqual """aste\*risk"""
      S.sanitize("""ques?tion""") mustEqual """ques\?tion"""
      S.sanitize("""co:lon""") mustEqual """co\:lon"""
    }

    "escape set operators" in {
      S.sanitize("gin AND tonic") mustEqual """gin \A\N\D tonic"""
      S.sanitize("now OR never") mustEqual """now \O\R never"""
      S.sanitize("NOT never") mustEqual """\N\O\T never"""
    }

    "not escape set operators if part of words" in {
      S.sanitize("MANDATE") mustEqual "MANDATE"
      S.sanitize("NOTORIOUS") mustEqual "NOTORIOUS"
    }

    "not escape set operators if lowercase" in {
      S.sanitize("and or not") mustEqual "and or not"
    }

    "collapse excess whitespaces" in {
      S.sanitize("Y u no use  single \t space??") mustEqual """Y u no use single space\?\?"""
    }

    "escape last quote if number of quotes is odd" in {
      S.sanitize("""Che "Guevarra" wears me" on his t shirt""") mustEqual """Che "Guevarra" wears me\" on his t shirt"""
    }

    "not escape any quotes if number of quotes even" in {
      S.sanitize("""Using these "lasers", we punch a hole in the "ozone layer"... """) mustEqual
        """Using these "lasers", we punch a hole in the "ozone layer"... """
    }
  }
}
```